# How to move cursor in a webpage by keyboard only?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard, webpage

Suppose we can't use a mouse but only the keyboard. How can we move the cursor and select different items in a webpage? (in Firefox or Chromium-browser)

For example,

- when I open uperuser.com, I can use Tab to move the cursor around different selectable items. But for the little notification for reputation change, I can't figure out how to move within its drop down menu to move between SE sites.
- Sometimes tab doesn't go over all the selectible items, it may skip some, for example, when I post a question, I can't jump out of related questions and the input box for typing questions.
- Currently, my usage of tab isn't convenient, if I want to jump to a selectable item quickly, without going one by one in an order.

Thanks.

PS: I am Ubuntu user.

Comment: AFAIK, it's completely dependent upon the Tab order of the web page elements and is determined by whomever "coded" the web page. This isn't something you can control with your browser. Some elements may not have a Tab order and may not be selectable via keyboard alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends, there are several ways.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/8664/how-to-get-numpad-out-of-mouse-emulation-mode

or you could use xdotool

http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml#mouse_commands